# Best way to use a PyQt5 Model within a PyQt5 TreeModel

Tags: python, design-patterns, sqlalchemy, pyqt5, qabstractitemmodel

I have a code structure already using SQLAlchemy to make declarative models.

Example Tables/Models:

- Repository

  - repository_id
  - name
  - owner
- Endpoint

  - repository_id
  - endpoint_id
  - name
  - method
- Contexts

  - context_id
  - endpoint_id
  - parent_context_id
  - config
  - created_on
  - created_by

I'd like to make a QtTree to select a Repository > Endpoint > Context > Nested Context.

Similar to how an IDE may have a browser view that shows both folders/packages/files and give different right-click menus to each.

I'm trying to understand what the "proper" way of implementing this would be.

I've looked at GitHub to see what other people have done, but most of small open source apps just use a TreeWidget and have more or less hard-coded views or large projects like "Eric" which are doing things like Lazy Loading... and I'm not sure if it's total overkill for what I'm looking to do -- the 1700+ lines of custom implementation code in Eric has seemed to give more feedback than anything else I've seen... but I still have the issue that my model issue is already semi-defined once...

Since I'm primarily using SQLAlchemy for the rest of the application, should I first create/use a "SqlAlchemyTableModel" to scaffold each model, then create a "BrowserModel" that performs the logic to create these?

Should the RepositoryModel/EndpointModel/ContextModel be a subclass, or is it sufficient to just create them through a generic class?

Ideally I'd like the Repository/Endpoint/Etc to have different icons in the list and different ContextMenus.   Should these be set in their model?   Through the parent model?   Through a decorator proxy?  Through view delegates?

I feel like I have a million hammers but I have no clue if what I'm looking at is a nail or a screw.

Reference:
https://github.com/davy39/eric/blob/master/UI/BrowserModel.py

Comment: I think you should start by explaining the structure of your data, for example you indicate *Repository > Endpoint > Context > Nested Context* but with what you indicate in your scheme I do not see what relationship a Repository has with an Endpoint. On the other hand, the context-menu, icons, etc. has nothing to do with the model but with the view so it would be good to leave it aside in this question. And finally it would be nice to show how you use SQLAlchemy to understand you better

Comment: @eyllanesc, your answered my last question on here and I highly appreciate it. -- I missed the repository_id in the Endpoint model. -- The icon is something I see a lot of models produce by overriding Data() and returning when the display role calls for it.   It seems like a lot of the Tree code I see on Github and live projects "take shortcuts" because they are using only one column to truly represent their model and they're one-off views/models.

Comment: As far as SQL Alchemy goes, it is used for doing complex JOINs and sorting elsewhere in the project, but this particular part doesn't use anything that "requires" it, I could use the built-in SqlTableModel... but then I have to duplicate the database setup and parts of defining the structure of the model

Comment: 1) The icon is trivial, if the structure is well defined then placing an icon is very simple so I say that we should not be distracted in that. 2) From what I understand you, you don't want to duplicate things, so it seems that you want to implement a "SQLAlchemyXModel" that's why I asked you how you handle "Repository> Endpoint> Context> Nested Context" through SQLAlchemy. 3) Could you explain in more detail about the "Nested Context" and parent_context_id.

Comment: As you realize the last 2 parts of my comment is to understand the structure of the information (the model) and thus be able to implement a suitable Qt Model. In GH there are many small projects that use dummy like QTreeWidget but in complex structures you need customized views and models as you point out.

Comment: @eyllanesc 1.) good point, that is trivial.  2.). Through most of this part of the code base SQLAlchemy is just used to join the tables, but it's also the Session manager for all other parts of the codebase.   The SQL Alchemy models contain a lot of the business logic for things such as sanitization of data before adding to the database, creating managing versioning for each Context object.

Comment: @eyllanesc 3.) Contexts are naturally part of a tree, a context parses input and generate output, that output is a scope that is passed to a child contexts and they generate an output in return.  Currently the structure is where every Context runs in the scope of its parents.   Contexts only ever have 1 parent, and because of the nature of how they're run if a context needs to be duplicated for another scope, it's cloned so changes don't effect other usages of that context.

Comment: So far I understand very little about how your structure works and with it I will not be able to help you unfortunately, I need more real information about the structure: a real example would help a lot. If you do not provide quality information then I will continue my way. I will explain from your point of view your post: Up to "Repository> Endpoint> Context> Nested Context." There is quality information since it allows us to understand the structure, then you ask for something very generic and in SO we answer specific questions

Comment: (maybe you should ask in https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/), Then you indicate the trivial examples of GH (QtreeWidget) and the elegant “eric” model, after You ask many questions that without quality information it is impossible to answer.